# Display CLI program on HDMI connected monitor while connected via SSH

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi

I'm have a monitor connected to my Pi via HDMI. There is no GUI OS installed, only the command line. I don't have a keyboard, so I'm SSHing into my Pi.

I have a python script that displays some text. I want to, from my SSH session, cause that python script to display its text on my HDMI connected monitor, instead of in my SSH console. Hopefully that makes sense.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try redirecting output of your script to `/dev/tty1`. However, there may be permissions issues...

Comment: I get a `not writeable` error when I try to redirect sys.stdout to `/dev/tty1`

Comment: However it does work if I just `echo 'text' > /dev/tty1` . That's pretty awesome

Comment: Got it to work in python after all. Had the wrong file permissions. Thanks!